# Lebesgue measurability

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

For what $n$ it is (in)consistent that all $\Sigma^1_n/\Pi^1_n$ sets are Lebesgue measurable ?
I remember that there is a result that if all $\Sigma^1_3$ are Lebesgue measurable then
$\omega_1$ is inaccessible in $\sf{L}$.

Comment: Assuming relatively mild(!) large cardinal axioms are consistent, it is consistent that all projective sets are Lebesgue measurable. Specifically this follows from infinitely many Woodin cardinals with a measurable above them, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Consistency-wise, an inaccessible cardinal is enough. Indeed, assuming the existence of an inaccessible cardinal, it is consistent that all sets are Lebesgue measurable. This is the content of a famous result due to Solovay. He proved that if $\kappa$ is inaccessible and $G$ is Col$(\omega,\kappa)$-generic, then $V[G]$ has an inner model satisfying "every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable".

Comment: @SebaThei But does not Solovay model satisfy Choice? However, Solovay's proof also shows that by Levy collapse an inaccessible to $\omega_1$, we have that every set in $L(\mathbb{R})$ (especially, $\Sigma^1_n$ and $\Pi^1_n$ set) is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes, essentially that’s the point. Also, one can prove that in $L(\mathbb{R})$, as computed in the generic extension given by the collapse you mentioned, every set has the Perfect Set Property and the Baire Property. In particular, Choice fails in $L(\mathbb{R})$.